# Mongodb return each distinct item with array of results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I have a collection of customers in different states like:

```
{
  name: "A",
  location: "Boston"
},
{
  name: "A",
  location: Los Angeles
},
{
  name: "B",
  location: Cleveland
}
```

I want to return each distinct customer name with an array of locations like this:

```
[
{ name: "A", location: [ "Boston", "Los Angeles" ]},
{ name: "B", location: [ "Cleveland" ] }
]
```

Any idea how to do this?  I can run a distinct and get:

```
>db.customers.distinct("name");
[ "A", "B" ]
```

But I cannot figure out how to get each customers locations in an array.  I have also tried aggregation pipelines with no luck.  I think $map or map-reduce is probably the way to go but I still cannot figure this out.

Comment: You have to use $group. `db.customers.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$name", location:{"$push":"$location"}}})`.

Comment: perfect!  Thanks @Veeram

Comment: @Veeram assuming there is a date in the documents, can they be sorted by date before the aggregation so that the locations are in order by date?

Comment: yeah add the `{$sort:{datefield:-1}}` before $group stage.